# How to user DefaultHandler class in BlackBerry

Tags: sax, global-asax

In BlackBerry application I am using SAX parser to parse my XML.I know how to do SAX parsing using ContentHandler interface.But i want to parse my XML by using the DefaultHandler class
so that i can provide definitions of only those methods that i require.
can any one please provide me a sample code as how can i use the DefaultHandler
class to do SAX parsing in BlackBerry

Answer (score 0):

for xml like

```
<items>
<item>
  <title>title content </title>
   ..
</item>
...
</items>



class XMLRSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    static final String TITLE = "title";
    static final String ITEM = "item";

    boolean isItem = false;
    boolean isTitle = false;
    Vector items = new Vector();
    String value = "";

    private Item currentItem = null;

    public XMLRSSHandler() {
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)) {
           currentItem = new Item();
        } else if (currentItem != null) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
                isTitle = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (isTitle) {
            value = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {
        if (isTitle && name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
            isTitle = false;
            currentItem.setTitle(value);
            return;
        }
        if (currentAItem != null
                && (name.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)) {
            Logger.debug("Loaded Item " + currentItem.getTitle());
            items.addElement(currentArticle);
            currentItem= null;
        }
    }
}
```